# Is there a branch of math that studies how information can be translated from one domain to another?

Tags: soft-question

I was just thinking to myself, "it would be cool if I could visualize all the classes in the framework on my screen" but then I thought "what if there are more classes than there are pixels?"...

Anyway, it seems like something that mathematics might formalize in order to answer a question like, "given N pixels, how many Y would you possibly be able to visualize?"

I'd just like to know what to call this so I can Google it.

Comment: Category theory? - If by information you mean structure, rather than some quantification thereof.

Answer (score 2):

Your question as you ask it seems to be a combinatorics question.

Based on your title, you might want to look into information theory.

Answer (score 2):

[Information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) is a branch of math/computer science that has to do with limits on storing, compressing, and transferring information. This sounds like what you are asking about.